# Cannot execute Python file in IGoR (a immunerepertoire analysis software)

Tags: python

Recently, I've been trying to learn how to use the [IGoR](https://github.com/qmarcou/IGoR) software for immunorepertoire analysis. But I encountered a problem in parsing the output file. The author provided the manual, however, I cannot fulfill the function and get the results. Below is the link to the manual and the key words provided by author. Maybe the author is very busy and he cannot respond immediately.

- [github link](https://github.com/qmarcou/IGoR)
- [manual](https://qmarcou.github.io/IGoR/)
- [question](https://github.com/qmarcou/IGoR/issues/48)

> The output of this Counter is a semicolon separated values file with one field for each event realization, associated mismatches/errors/mutations indices on the read, the scenario rank, its associated probability and the sequence index. Python functions to parse the output of the Best scenario counter can be found in the pygor.counters.bestscenarios submodule.

Or this is the content in this `.py` file:

```
import copy

import pandas

from ...models.genmodel import GenModel
from ...utils import utils
def read_bestscenarios_values(scenarios_file, model_parms_file):
best_scenarios_df = read_bestscenarios_indices(filename=scenarios_file)
gen_model = GenModel(model_parms_file=model_parms_file)
return scenarios_indices2values(best_scenarios=best_scenarios_df,
                                input_genmodel=gen_model)
```

and bulalalala!

How can I use the `.py` file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a new python script, `import pygor` then call e.g. `read_bestscenarios_values('path/to/example_scenarios_file', '/path/to/example_model_parms_file')` in your script, perhaps?

Comment: In any case, you should update your question with a link to your `.csv` file, any model parameters file and provide the *relevant* details of any script you've come up with so far by editing these into your question.

Comment: Hi Anaksunaman, Thanks for your help. I am a layman, and I tried as your suggestions. but it still doesn't work well. Could help give a detail command line for this, Thanks a million! I attached the pygor.zip file as the github link [link](https://github.com/decenwang/IGoR-trainning-) , there should be several submodules, so if I can run anyone of them, I can run the others. you can find the  *.py file in /pygor/counters/bestscenarios/bestscenarios.py and a *.csv file can be used for analysis. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed `import` statement and command example:

```
from pygor.counters.bestscenarios import bestscenarios

try:
    best_scenarios = bestscenarios.read_bestscenarios_values('/path/to/best_scenarios_counts.csv', '/path/to/model_parms.txt')
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    exit()

print('\n')
print(best_scenarios)
```

---

*Notes*

- *This is a simple example file to make sure everything "works". I have no clue if this produces desirable output.*
- *The basic `import` statement above is (approximately) e.g. `from folder.folder.folder import python_file.py`.*
- *The `print()` syntax used here is for Python 3.x. The same is true for the `try/except` block.*

---